# Similarity test of binary time series data

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, binary-data

I have two datasets of binary time series data and I would like to prove that these two datasets are similar.

The datasets are coming form binary sensors installed in a smart home and they reflect the interactions of a person living there. The two datasets are coming from the same smart house and have the same configuration (same number of sensors and same placement). But one dataset was generated by a person who lived there for a period of time and the other is for another person who lived there at a different time. The datasets are of the same length and have the same datetime stamp.

I would like to prove that the two datasets are generated by the same person. So, I'm assuming that what I need is a test that shows that these two datasets come from the same probability distribution.

I'm not an expert so sorry if I'm not being clear.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for you to get a very useful answer. Please add more details about the data sets, what type of "similarity" you care about, and how you intend to use the results of the analysis.

Comment: I think if you wanted to demonstrate that time series A and time series B came from the same person, you'd want a control dataset that is demonstrably distinct from A and B.